# What should a community ad for gardening.stackexchange look like?

Tags: discussion

Fully launched StackExchange sites can show community ads for anything their community chooses. There are premade templates for ads for Area51 proposals:

[area51 ad http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/1369.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/1369.png)

but they're perhaps not the best for betas, since they still say "proposal" and are pretty generic. Is the premade one good enough? Or does anyone have something they'd like to offer up as an ad for any sites interested in advertising for gardening?

For example, [text on a simple image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247044/133299) can look good. Here's one from space:

[image: space community ad]

Here are the image requirements:

> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels** (except [440x500 seems to work too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248622/133299) and looks better on high-resolution monitors)
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Comment: (I'm asking mainly because cooking.stackexchange might want to advertise for gardening, but perhaps other sites could want it too.)

Comment: I don't know how to edit photos all that well. I guess you can't use any photo off of google?

Comment: I remember you! You answered my [first cooking question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23513/how-can-i-tell-when-red-bananas-are-ripe). Anyway, I think GL could potentially have a rather nice looking ad. I just don't know how to design one myself. But I really don't like the premade A51 ad.

Comment: dropping an ad over on http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/ probably wouldn't hurt either. I know we occasionally pass questions to one another, and there's some obvious overlap when they start talking about composting and home-growing vegetables.

Comment: Has it worked out yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?

[image: Picture pulled from Wikipedia with text added.]

Here is the smaller size at 300 x 250:

[image]

I had to go this route because my original was smaller than the 600 size ... when I tried to blow it up, the lettering became pixelated.

The original picture would not format as we'd want and still allow it to work right. Here is another attempt using a different picture ... let me know if this works, though I don't think it's as stark as the other picture.

[image]

And yes, I think orchids are awesome, lol.

Try #5 ... Here is the original chopped down to the correct size. Let me know if it works or which you like better. I actually like how this one came out.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it would! One thing: on [cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) though it'd sit inside a border, the off-white background there might not contrast as much as you'd like with the off-white of our site background.

Comment: I was thinking the background and the flower had enough contrast to really set it off. It's just something I threw together. Could do something more if required.

Comment: Okay! Posted: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/2045/1672 If anything else comes up I can always swap that one out for an updated version.

Comment: Attribution may be required for [that picture](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cattleya_photo_D_Ramey_Logan.jpg)?

Comment: @GolezTrol ... If it can be added, the image has a [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) license. I found it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchidaceae#mediaviewer/File:Cattleya_photo_D_Ramey_Logan.jpg).

Comment: Would you be able to update this for the new ad size? (300 x 250 pixels, or 600 x 500 pixels for retina)

Comment: @Jefromi ... Sure, I'll try to do it in the morning. Should not be an issue as I believe I saved the original file. I'll edit this post and throw it in here.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post it over at cooking as well if you get a chance: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2152/1672

Comment: @Jefromi - I'll have to go back and recreate this ... I thought it would be an easy fix, but I got the dimensions backwards. I'll have to try again this afternoon. I created an account over on cooking just to post it, just to realize I had it wrong ... argh. I *will* get it done, however.

Comment: I love this one! I've seen it before and think it looks great. Thank you all for your hard work.

Comment: @Sue - Yah, if the original picture was portrait instead of landscape I could use it ... unfortunately ...

Comment: I put the new (bottom one) image over on Cooking.SE ... Hopefully it meets with people's expectations.

Comment: I think it's beautiful! I love the clarity! I don't know if those are dewdrops or raindrops, or maybe it just got watered, but it has a very refreshing look. I love the lettering too - bold but not intrusive. It's a lovely combination. I'll be interested to hear what others think.

Comment: Thanks Sue ... I'm just glad to help. :D

Comment: Help you do, and we reap the benefit!